# 2018 MBP doesn't work w external monitor except after reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a 2018 MBP, Touchbar, running MacOS 10.13.6. I connect it to a Dell P2715Q external monitor. I've noticed that it generally works, but after a week or so of usage (I plug/unplug my monitor as I move the Mac around), the external monitor no longer displays any images (even though it is detected, as my laptop screen switches to the 2 monitor arrangement).

I've tried this with multiple cables and multiple P2715Q monitors. The only solution I've found is to reboot when this happens.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue, and do they have any ideas?